# create polygon using GMSPolygon google map iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

**I want to create polygon like this polygon using native feature of google map SDK:**

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What you need to do is create a polygon first. And then add click event to it. Then in click event function, you can move the polygon to the location where your finger is currently pointing using CGPoint.